# Create custom login page for windows( NTLM) authentication in sharepoint server 2013

Tags: 2013, windows-authentication, custom-login-page

I am trying to create a Custom Login Page for Windows Authentication in my SharePoint 2013 Web Application.

Please point me to right directions as to how I can have this implem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Waqas mentioned, you cannot use forms to log in if using WIA. There is an alternative: using a pre-auth reverse proxy. There are many vendors who have pre-auth reverse proxy products. Microsoft has Web Application Proxy (WAP) in conjunction with ADFS 3.0. This will allow you to use Kerberos on your Web Application in SharePoint while having a forms-based login experience through WAP. The ADFS login page can be customized, e.g. add branding as shown at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx.

Comment: but , i want to have a simple custom page login for sharepoint , i can not understand why all this configuration ?

Comment: WIA uses a challenge and response method. The browser sends an anonymous request to the web server, and the web server responds with a challenge for a username and password. The browser then prompts you for that information. This is fundamentally how it works. What you're asking for is forms based authentication, where the user navigates to a page and inputs their password. FBA and WIA are not the same. So if you want to continue using WIA, but want the FBA login experience, then you need a pre-auth reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, Windows Authentication will prompt for credentials with a pop-up. Any 'custom logon page' will require forms-based authentication.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7270c7f-7ddb-4ec6-8564-9ef4ab11bd6c/custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

But there are still reference in that article or below blog which guide you.

http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2015/02/23/sharepoint-2013-custom-login-page-for-form-based-authentication/